# Flex/Bison: Bad token management?

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, lex, flex-lexer

I've a problem in my lexer and in my parser.

First, in my lexer I've a line like that:

```
"if"    beginScope(stOTHER); return IF;
```

And in my parser:

```
stmt: IF '(' exp ')' stmts
...
stmts: stmt
       | '{' stmt_list '}'
       | '{' '}'
```

In a code like that:

```
if(sth) {
    dosth;
}

if(other) {
    doothersth;
}
```

beginScope will be called two times, because ( I think ) Bison don't know where is the end of the `if` statement, so when it found the `IF` token, he takes that as the end of the `if` statement, and read it a second time to start the other `if` statement...

Please help me...

Comment: Can you call `beginScope()` for "{" in your Flex file? That way, you can `endScope()` when you see "}". Just have these single-character expressions return a token like OPENBRACE and CLOSEBRACE to Bison.

Comment: No I can't, because beginScope needs a type in parameter, and there is not always a "{" as you can see

Comment: Move the `beginScope` operation into your parser actions.  Use a [mid-rule action](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Mid_002dRule-Actions.html) if necessary.  The lexer must not have side effects, for exactly the reason you have discovered.

Comment: Oh yes! The mid-rule action is perfect, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Zack mentioned in the comments, you should call `beginScope` from a parser action:

```
stmt: IF { beginScope(stOTHER); } '(' exp ')' stmts
```